# The Intercept of a categorical multiple regression R is not the mean value?

Tags: r, regression, lm, tidyverse, intercept

Let's say I have 2 (categorical) variables and one continuous:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(
  depression=rnorm(90,10,2),
  schooling_dummy=c(0,1,2),
  sex_dummy=c(0,1)
)
```

When I regress **depression on sex** (0 or 1), the intercept is 10.0436, what is the mean of sex = 0. Ok!

```
ds %>% group_by(sex_dummy) %>% 
+   summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=4))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  sex_dummy `formatC(mean(depression), format = "f", digits = 4)`
      <dbl> <chr>                                                
1      0    10.0436                                              
2      1.00 10.1640
```

The same thing happens when I regress **depression on schooling**. The intercept value is **10.4398**. The mean of schooling = 0 is the same.

```
ds %>% group_by(schooling_dummy) %>% 
+   summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=4))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  schooling_dummy `formatC(mean(depression), format = "f", digits = 4)`
            <dbl> <chr>                                                
1            0    10.4398                                              
2            1.00 9.7122                                               
3            2.00 10.1593
```

Now, when I compute a model with both variables, **why the intercept is not the mean when both groups = 0? The regression **intercept is 10.3796**, but the mean when sex = 0, and schooling is = 0 is **10.32548**:

```
ds %>% group_by(schooling_dummy,sex_dummy) %>% 
+   summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=5))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: schooling_dummy [?]
  schooling_dummy sex_dummy `formatC(mean(depression), format = "f", digits = 5)`
            <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                                
1            0         0    10.32548                                             
2            0         1.00 10.55404                                             
3            1.00      0    9.59305                                              
4            1.00      1.00 9.83139                                              
5            2.00      0    10.21218                                             
6            2.00      1.00 10.10648
```

When I predict the model when both are 0:

```
predict(mod3, data.frame(sex_dummy=0, schooling_dummy=0))
       1 
10.37956
```

This result is related to depression (of course...) but still not What I was expecting, since:
[image: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpret-the-intercept/]
(Reference: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpret-the-intercept/)

What is the same for this [previous forum post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262906/interpreting-estimates-of-categorical-predictors-in-linear-regression)
I aware of my variables are categorical and I'm adjusting my script, as you can reproduce using this code below: 
Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(
  depression=rnorm(90,10,2),
  schooling_dummy=c(0,1,2),
  sex_dummy=c(0,1)
)
mod <- lm(data=ds, depression ~ relevel(factor(sex_dummy), ref = "0"))
summary(mod)
ds %>% group_by(sex_dummy) %>% 
  summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=4))

mod2 <- lm(data=ds, depression ~ relevel(factor(schooling_dummy), ref = "0"))
summary(mod2)
ds %>% group_by(schooling_dummy) %>% 
  summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=4))

mod3 <- lm(data=ds, depression ~ relevel(factor(sex_dummy), ref = "0") + 
             relevel(factor(schooling_dummy), ref = "0"))
summary(mod3)
ds %>% group_by(schooling_dummy,sex_dummy) %>% 
  summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=5))

predict(mod3, data.frame(sex_dummy=0, schooling_dummy=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Two errors in your thinking (although your R code works so it's not a programming error.

First and foremost you violated your own statement you have **not** dummy coded `schooling` it does not have only zeroes and ones it has 0,1 & 2.

Second you forgot the interaction effect in your `lm` modeling...

Try this...

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(
  depression=rnorm(90,10,2),
  schooling_dummy=c(0,1,2),
  sex_dummy=c(0,1)
)
# if you explicitly make these variables factors not integers R will do the right thing with them
ds$schooling_dummy<-factor(ds$schooling_dummy)
ds$sex_dummy<-factor(ds$sex_dummy)
ds %>% group_by(schooling_dummy,sex_dummy) %>%
    summarise(formatC(mean(depression),format="f", digits=5))
# you need an asterisk in your lm model to include the interaction term
lm(depression ~ schooling_dummy * sex_dummy, data = ds)
```

The results give you the mean(s) you were expecting...

```
Call:
lm(formula = depression ~ schooling_dummy * sex_dummy, data = ds)

Coefficients:
                (Intercept)             schooling_dummy1             schooling_dummy2  
                  10.325482                    -0.732433                    -0.113305  
                 sex_dummy1  schooling_dummy1:sex_dummy1  schooling_dummy2:sex_dummy1  
                   0.228561                     0.009778                    -0.334254
```

and FWIW you can avoid this sort of accidental misuse of categorical variables if your data is coded as characters to begin with... so if your data is coded this way:

```
ds <- data.frame(
  depression=rnorm(90,10,2),
  schooling=c("A","B","C"),
  sex=c("Male","Female")
)
```

You're less likely to make the same mistake plus the results are easier to read...

Comment: Hello, @Chuck P, your comment was very useful. When I specify my model using the interaction term (*) instead of the additive term (+), it works. But I still not understanding **why** I need an interaction term to intercept becomes the mean value. In my mind, when I have two categorical independent variables, by definition, the intercept will be the mean value when both are 0. From where I've got **10.3796**. I'll appreciate hearing from you about this explanation. Thanks much.

Comment: @Luis if you don't include the interaction term you are not specifying the most complete possible model and the means are adjusted accordingly. I'm going to send you back to The Analysis Factor [link here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interaction-dummy-variables-in-linear-regression/) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @chuck-p, I read again the website, but they don't explain the rationale of this question. Reading "Econometrics", by Wooldridge, he states clearly the intercept is the mean / average value when X = 0. If possible, could you please reference other book or website. Thanks much again.

Comment: @Luis I don't have a copy of the book you reference but here's a free text book that explains it pretty well in section 16.2 starting on page 506.  Notice you do get the mean when x=0 as long as you specify the full and complete model to `lm`.  [Learning Statistics with R](http://www.compcogscisydney.com/learning-statistics-with-r.html)

Comment: Dear @chuck-p, thanks for sharing this book. I read all chapter, what clearly state what I wrote. Please, have a look: "Digging further back into our decaying memories of high school (sorry, for some of us high school was a long time ago), we remember that the intercept is interpreted as “the value of y that you get when x “ 0”. Similarly, a slope of m means that if you increase the x-value by 1 unit, then the y-value goes up by m units" (p. 464). In all book examples, models are additive (b0+b1+b2). I will be happy if you provide another reference.Thanks much for all your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry @Luis I give up.  You are picking and choosing what you read rather than doing what I suggested.  The very point is that there is a difference between a simple additive model and one with interactions.  `b0+b1+b2` is different than `b0*b1*b2` and you will get different answers from `lm` **which is exactly what you got.** If you read the pages in the chapter I suggested rather than the pages that you think prove your point it might help.  Anyway good luck I'm done with this thread.

Comment: Dear @chuck-p, I really appreciate you book indication and, yes, I read to book and the chapter you recommended. I'm not cherry-picking information. It says "An interaction between A and B is said to occur whenever the effect of Factor A is different, depending on which level of Factor B we’re talking about". I was **not** expecting both variables I created in R (one independent of another) could be seen as a case of an interaction. Anyway, thanks much for your support. That was really nice. :)

Comment: @Luis you're welcome.  It's not a very big interaction notice your difference in means is very small 10.3796 versus 10.32548 but it is the explanation and not some error in the math or in R's calculations.

Comment: Dear @chuck-p, thanks again for your effort explaining this output. I really appreciate. I'm reading more books about that and as soon as I can understand all math behind that, I'll post here and use the @ to mark your as well. Thanks much. =)